# Check if timestamp is within tsrange

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, date-range

Is it possible to construct an on-the-fly `tsrange` and check if a value is within that?

I have a table that has two fields, `session_start` and `session_end` and I want to run a query that checks if a passed value is between those two values. Something along these lines (not valid SQL!):

```
SELECT pk FROM sessions WHERE ? IN [session_start, session_end)
```

I am unsure about the exact syntex for a literal `tsrange` and also how to check for inclusion (`IN` does not seem to work`.

Note that both the passed value as well as `session_start` and `session_end` are `TIMESTAMP` fields / values.

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [range constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT) for that:

```
SELECT rangetype(lower, upper[, bounds]);
-- bounds can be '[]', '[)' (default), '(]', '()'

-- in your case:
SELECT pk FROM sessions WHERE ? <@ tsrange(session_start, session_end, '[)');
```

*Note*: the containment [operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html) is `<@` for ranges (not `IN`).